Unable to Install Windows 10 LTSC 32-bit on KVM Virt-Manager (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS)
I was previously running Windows 7 Starter Edition without any issues on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS using Virt-Manager. I decided to switch to Windows 10 LTSC 32-bit on KVM Virt-Manager, but I encountered an issue after restarting the installation process. The error message displayed is:
Windows Setup could not configure Windows to run on this computer's hardware.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Ensured that my system meets the hardware requirements for Windows 10
LTSC 32-bit.
Verified the integrity of the Windows 10 LTSC ISO file.
Checked the KVM settings and configuration.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or could provide guidance on how to resolve this?

Please do not post pictures of simple one line text messages. Cut and past into question and if you can not do that type it in. Having a picture forces anyone trying to help to exit your question and load a second screen to see it.
